# Laravel: always adding user/{id} to routes or different method

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel application. In the routes file, I have

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'roles'], 'roles' => ['buyer']], function() {
        Route::get('dashboard/buyer', ['as' => 'buyer_dashboard', 'uses' => 'User\Buyer\DashboardController@index']);
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'roles'], 'roles' => ['seller']], function() {
        Route::get('dashboard/seller', ['as' => 'seller_dashboard', 'uses' => 'User\Seller\DashboardController@index']);
    });

});
```

I have a middleware that basically checks if the id as supplied in the route, is the same as the current logged in user. If this is not the case, I return an error page. The reason for having this is that I want to prevent that a user can access the dashboard of another user. I also want to prevent that a user can place a bid for someone else (by changing the id in the http request)

The issue is that in the first route, the id is referring to the user. In the second route, the id is referring to the lot id.

Am I obliged to change the second route to:

```
Route::get('{id}/lot/{lot}/bid/create', ['as' => 'buyer_lot_bid_create', 'uses' => 'User\Buyer\BidsController@create']);
```

where the first id refers to the user so that I can check the id of the user?

Or is there another way to prevent users from accessing other users pages without explicitly passing the user/{id} in the route?

Comment: you can check the user id of the logged in user by using auth::user->id(); in your code. no need to get from the http request.

Comment: Well, I understand that auth::user->id() is the current logged in user. But it does not catch the situation where a logged in user can access the content from another user. Say a user with id 1 is logged in and has access to his own dashboard via /user/1/dashboard, then he could still access /user/2/dashboard. Therefore I'm checking on the route {id} also. You see what I mean?

Comment: ok so in the controller function where you use the the user id from the url, try to check it with the auth::user->id() if both are not same then redirect the page with 404 or 401 as you want.

Comment: Doing that in middleware indeed. So that means all routes should always start with user/id which is what I don't like. I was looking for a way to implicitly pass the user id.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using `Gate`?

Comment: if you dont want to get it from url then only one option remain that use the auth id.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in a middleware sounds like a bad idea. You've already come up against one exception to your middleware rule, and you'll certaily come across more.

There's two ways to do this:

1. Using laravel's built in authorisation tools: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization
2. If the check is that the "id as supplied in the route, is the same as the current logged in user" then there's no need to pass the user's id in via the route at all. The user can just visit eg. `/dashboard/buyer` with no params in the route. Who's dashboard are they visiting? The one of the logged in user, of course. So there's no way for a user to even try to visit another user's dashboard. Likewise with bidding. You can make your `bid` endpoint so that the bidder's id is not passed in via a route - it's just set to the id of the logged in user in your controller method. So again, there's no way to even try to bid on behalf of another user.

Comment: Thanks. Will try option 2 for now. On option 1, am using https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission but not sure how that can come in handy here?

Comment: You don't need 3rd party for that unless the schema would get overcomplicated, which doesn't seem

Comment: It doesn't look like https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission will provide anything useful over Laravel's built in auth stuff in this context. But yeah, in any case, 2 is a better option if that's all you need.

Comment: Yes, I have changed the code so that I do not need to pass the userid. I added the routes file to the original question. I'm still struggling though that I need a separate route for buyer (/user/dashboard/buyer) and seller (user/dashboard/seller) so I might decide to check the role in the controller, but I don't like that approach too much. Also for that, the suggestion below of Cristo could work, but need to implement that. Will report back once finished.

Answer (score 0):

```
  class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        public function boot(GateContract $gate)
        {
            $this->registerPolicies($gate);

            $gate->define('see-profile', function ($user, $profile) {
                return $user->id === $profile->user_id;
            });
        }
```

Controller:

```
public function profile($id)
{
    $post = Profile::findOrFail($id);
    if (Gate::denies('see-profile', $profile)) {
      abort(403);
    }
 }
```